# Having trouble stacking one div on top of another wordpress functions

Tags: css, wordpress

I am constructing comments.php in a custom wordpress theme.

I have the post meta data wrapped in one div. I have comment_text function wrapped in another div. The post meta data is on top of the comments. The issue I am having is getting the bottom of post meta data and the top of comment_text to join. There is space between the two. Both are inside of ol li.

I tried putting both in a wrapper div and that didn't work. Removing all padding, margins on the divs and the li and that doesn't help. Here is my code:

```
<div class="comment_wrapper">
        <div class="post_meta_data">
        Posted by: <?php comment_author_link(); ?> on <?php comment_date();?>
        </div><!--end .post_meta_data-->
        <div class="comment_text">
        <?php comment_text(); ?>
        </div><!--end .comment_text-->
        </div><!--end .comment_wrapper-->
```

[image: The issue]

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, wrapped them both in a div then added margins to that div. fixed the problem